# How can I get the Facebook app on the IOS5 simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I need a custom logon screen that supports multiple identity providers (OAuth).  When the user selects Facebook, I'm testing the Facebook SDK in various conditions

iOS 5

- With iOS app installed
- Without iOS app installed

iOS 6

- With iOS app installed (default). User not logged in via "settings"
- With iOS app installed (default). User logged in via "settings"

I understand in various circumstances either a Web Page will be shown, the app itself, or a popup button.

**Question**

- Is it possible for me to "sideload" the Facebook app on the iOS 5 simulator so I can test iOS5 with the app installed?
- Aside from purchasing a device just so I can install iOS 5 on it, how else can I test this?

Comment: Not possible without getting your hands on an i386/simulator-compiled version of the app.

Comment: Why are you supporting iOS 5? With the user base of iOS 5 so low, the impending iOS 7 update will only decrease this further. It doesn't seem economical to be wasting time support it. Purely out of interest; not saying you're doing anything wrong.

Comment: @CW0007007 With the phone buyback program, I heard the old devices won't be trashed, and will instead be sent to emerging economies (Africa, etc).  I'm trying to figure out where they are going so I can target apps for that unserviced population

Comment: Surely they will be loaded with the newest iOS though ?

Comment: @CW0007007 I didn't know if the devices will support

Answer (score 3):

There are many things you simply cannot test on the simulator and this is one of them. You have to test this by running your app on your device.

Comment: @aromkirk what about this video: https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10151871746615582 ?

Comment: @Narek well that *is* Facebook themselves demonstrating it. That means they have installed it from Xcode. :) (I know I'm a year late)

Answer (score 1):

no, its not possible to install the FB app on simulator, You have to have a real device for doing that.